# Eclipse with Android SDK failure to run blank project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have downloaded ADT Bundle with everything included http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. When I create Android Applicatio and I want to run I get sth like that. How to make it running.

```
[2012-11-21 10:18:00 - Test2] ------------------------------
[2012-11-21 10:18:00 - Test2] Android Launch!
[2012-11-21 10:18:00 - Test2] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Test2] Performing com.example.test2.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Test2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Test'
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Test2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test'
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] 
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-11-21 10:18:01 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: You must reboot PC and try again. actually one of the emulator instance is running and not allowing other to run.

Comment: do as @spanjeta says also delete and create a new avd

Answer (score 0):

While running your android app, it will loaded in new emulator. we cant able to run multiple emulator with single instance. Goto->Task Manager->adb(in running processes)->give end task->restart your eclipse and run your emulator.

Data partition already in use: This problem is based on your system RAM size and emulator ram size(allocating ram size while creating AVD) . If two emulator running in same instances,
the memory error will occur.